# Storing results of executor.submit to Stringbuffer.append

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have an `Executors.newfixedThreadPool()` which calls a submit and obviously submit returns future wrapped `StringBuffer` object. I need to get the append the result in response StringBuffer. I can get the result in `List<Future<StringBuffer>>` and again iterate to append in response `StringBuffer`. But I want to do this in single iteration like below But its appending future objects. Any way to achieve that?

```
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        response.append(es.submit(new Callable<StringBuffer>() {
            @Override
            public StringBuffer call() {
                StringBuffer res = new StringBuffer();
                res = processAddresses(addresses, addressLatch);
                return res;
            }
        }));
    }
    try {
        addressLatch.await();       
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    es.shutdownNow();
```

Comment: Do you need the order to be kept?

Comment: Not necessarily. But its good if we have order

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
    final StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        es.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                StringBuffer res = processAddresses(addresses, addressLatch);
                response.append(res);
            }
        });
    }
    es.shutdownNow();
    try {
        es.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    System.out.println(response);
```

But the order is not garantied to be kept

Comment: I have to have a addressLatch. It decides as how many addresses, I am going to display. Each process address will down the latch by one and lets say if down latch by 24 than shutdownNow will be invoked.

Comment: @upadhyayRakes OK, you can also use shutdown instead of shutdownNow

Comment: But what if other threads still running and I have reached my count to NUMBER. I don't need to process them anymore since Latch await is over. I am immediately shutting down without any wait.

Comment: @upadhyayRakes OK, but it's useless: shutdown will just stop accepting new tasks; il doesn't cancel tasks that were already submitted.

Comment: Correct. But I need to halt all and come out. Can you please suggest me If I have the list of all halted threads(returned from shutdownNow) and I can terminate them manually?

Comment: @upadhyayRakes they're not threads: they're tasks; you just need to call their run method.

Comment: @upadhyayRakes but you don't have to worry about those